# WCF Data Services: ChangeInterceptor not firing for Update

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a WCF Data Service (OData) that serves as the data repository for a larger system.  I'm trying to fire off specific methods based on operations on Entities in the repository.

Specifically, if someone changes a `Message` record, I want to hook into the pipeline.  I'm using `ChangeInterceptors` for this.

They work for `Add` and `Delete`.  However, nothing fires when an entity is updated.  I am concerned that the `DbContext` can not resolve the fact that the entity has changed, since the request is stateless.

This does not trigger the handler:

```
var whatever = from m in Messages
where m.MessageKey == 3
select m;

whatever.First().UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
this.SaveChanges();
```

Has anyone else faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was trying to use AttachTo() to handle the fact that my record was detached.  This flat out didn't work, and led to runtime exceptions like the following:

> This operation requires the entity be of an Entity Type, and has at least one key 
>   property.Parameter name: entity

At any rate, just use the update method and the change will be intercepted (and actually applied)

```
var whatever = (from m in Messages where m.MessageKey == 1
select m ).Single();

whatever.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
this.UpdateObject(whatever);
this.SaveChanges();
```